# How to set TextureFilter to Point to make example Bloom filter work?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, hlsl, fragment-shader

I have simple app that renders some particles and now I am trying to apply the bloom shader from the xna samplers ( http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/bloom ) to it, but I am running into this exception:

"XNA Framework HiDef profile requires TextureFilter to be Point when using texture format Vector4."

When the BloomComponent tries to end the sprite batch in the DrawFullscreenQuad method:

```
        spriteBatch.Begin(0, BlendState.Opaque, SamplerState.PointWrap, null, null, effect);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End(); //<------- Exception thrown here
```

It seems to be related to the pixel shaders that I am using to animate the particle. In a nutshell, I have a texture2d in vector4 format that holds particle positions, and another one for velocities. Here is a snippet from that area:

```
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(tempRenderTarget);
        animationEffect.CurrentTechnique = animationEffect.Techniques[technique];
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate,
                          BlendState.Opaque,
                          SamplerState.PointWrap,
                          DepthStencilState.DepthRead,
                          RasterizerState.CullNone,
                          animationEffect);

        spriteBatch.Draw(randomValues, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
```

What I comment out the code that calls the particle animation pixel shaders the bloom component runs fine. Is there some state that I need to reset to make the bloom work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointWrap;`

This will set the first `SamplerState` to `PointWrap`.  Do this before you call your `spriteBatch.Begin();`.

Comment: Sadly, this does not help, I get still the same exception

Comment: What should each of these states be set to?

Comment: I checked the states of these before and after the spriteBatch.begin() and with my particle system turned on and off, and they are always the same. DepthStencilState = none, BlendSate = AlphaBlend, and RasterizerState = CullCounterClockwise

Comment: I set the SamplerStates on element 1 instead of 0 and it works now. Thanks